# Where to obtain Google Analytics API access_token?

Tags: php, api, oauth, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

According to [Google Analytics API Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) OAuth as well as an Access Token can be used to access the stats of an page. Using OAuth is pretty complicated or at least it seems to me like that in php. However according to the docs I should also be able to use access_code as an get parameter.

I tried several ways to get the access_token from the [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com), but neither is working always returning the following error:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}
```

Thus I'm wondering how to get an none expireing api access code for my google analytics page properties? if possible at all?

Comment: have you ever got refresh-token?

Comment: No, i dont even know where to get the access token. I only get oauth data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your application on [Google Developer console](http://www.daimto.com/google-developers-console/) first.  Its a matter of using Oauth2 to get an access token.  You get an access token by first asking the user for permission to access their data.  Once you have been given permission you will then receive a refresh token which you can use to get an access token.

The following example uses the Google PHP client lib found on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).  The code was copied from my [Google Oauth2 PHP Tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/) the tutorial.

```
<?php         
require_once 'Google/Client.php';     
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';       
session_start();      
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("{devkey}");  
    $client->setClientId('{clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('{clientsecret}');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://www.daimto.com/Tutorials/PHP/Oauth2.php');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

    //For loging out.
    if ($_GET['logout'] == "1") {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
       }   

    // Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
    if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
        }        

    // Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);    

        // request user accounts
        $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

       foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $item) {
        echo "Account: ",$item['name'], "  " , $item['id'], "<br /> \n";        
        foreach($item->getWebProperties() as $wp) {
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WebProperty: ' ,$wp['name'], "  " , $wp['id'], "<br /> \n";    

            $views = $wp->getProfiles();
            if (!is_null($views)) {
                foreach($wp->getProfiles() as $view) {
                //  echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;View: ' ,$view['name'], "  " , $view['id'], "<br /> \n";    
                }
            }
        }
    } // closes account summaries

    }
 print "<br><br><br>";
 print "Access from google: " . $_SESSION['token']; 
?>
```

Comment: Thx @DalmTo for your explanation. This helped me a lot in getting startet. However I'm actually looking for an serverside solution as an background service which allows me persistent access without the necessaty of reauthentication everytime. I put this into a second question thou: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605470/how-to-access-google-analytics-api-from-a-serverside-background-service