# How to access Google Analytics API from a serverside background service?

Tags: php, oauth, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'd like to pull in data from google analytics into an own database through an background cron job without the user having to authenticate every time.

I do know [how to get an Google Analytics OAuth Access Token with user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399357/where-to-optain-google-analytics-api-access-token) as I asked previously. Using OAuth won't work, since it requires user interaction. According to [Google Analytics API Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) OAuth as well as an Access Token can be used to access the stats of an page once on a per session base. However I'm looking for an persistent way to implement this in an background service.

How can I access google analytics without user authentication or get an none expireing access token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the account in question is your own you can us a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  Make sure that you give the service account email address read access at the Account level to the Google analytics account and it will be able to read your data.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';

/************************************************
  The following 3 values an befound in the setting
  for the application you created on  Google 
  Developers console.
  The Key file should be placed in a location
  that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
  web root.

  In order to access your GA account you must
  Add the Email address as a user at the 
  ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin. 
 ************************************************/
$client_id = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$Email_address = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = '629751513db09cd21a941399389f33e5abd633c9-privatekey.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);

// seproate additional scopes with a comma
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";  

$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $Email_address,
    array($scopes),
    $key
    );

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);  
$accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

//calulating start date
$date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));

//Adding Dimensions
$params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:userType');
// requesting the data
$data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:78110423", $date->format('Y-m-d'),  date("Y-m-d"), "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );


?><html>
<?php echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . " - ".date("Y-m-d"). "\n";?>
<table>
<tr>
<?php
//Printing column headers
foreach($data->getColumnHeaders() as $header){  
    print "<td>".$header['name']."</td>";   
}
?>
</tr>
<?php
//printing each row.
foreach ($data->getRows() as $row) {    
    print "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";  
}

//printing the total number of rows
?>
<tr><td colspan="2">Rows Returned <?php print $data->getTotalResults();?> </td></tr>
</table>
</html>
<?php

?>
```

code ripped from tutorial [Google Service Account with PHP](http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/)

If this is not your account then you can use the normal Oauth2 method ask the use to authenticate you once then using the refresh token you will be able to access the data.  Using the code from your previous question.

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'' in D:\xampp\htdocs\ga_api\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php:358` Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Check the time on your machine Google invalid grant. It's an error with the authentication expires before you use it.

Comment: And how to synchronize my machine's time with Google, if you may answer?

Comment: the server clock needs to be in sync with NTP.  If we are talking a Linux machine check that the NTP demon is running.   It could also be that the refresh token you are using has expired.

Comment: Actually, there was some issue with the token, So I deleted all of them and created a new set of credentials. It seemingly fixed the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can only have around 26 refresh tokens once you hit  number 26 the oldest one will stop working.  Remember to only store one refresh token per user.

Comment: I'm getting this another error saying, `this user does not have Google Analytics account`. I'm using the generated email, similar to one provided here. If I change it back to my gmail id, it again starts throwing error `invalid grant`. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to open another question its not related to this code.  Google Analytics account take that email and try and login to the Google Analytics website, it wont work the user doesn't exist.

Comment: I was just asking, hoping that you had any ideas. Thanks for your help though

Comment: 1000+ example how to do it using that bloated library. What about simple php?

Comment: What without the library? Service account authentication isn't easy I recommend digging around in said library for how to do it.